# Angular Content Projection with iteration

Tags: angular, iteration, angular-content-projection

`myComponent.html` - `<my-component>`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of dataProvider">
    <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="tmpContent; context: {$implicit: item, item: item}">
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #tmpContent let-item="item">
    <div>
        {{item.id}}
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

And the usage:

```
 <my-component dataProvider='source'>
    <ion-label> test </ion-label>
 </my-component>
```

It seems iterate the correct number of times, but displays the `<ion-label>`, which is content projected only once in the last iteration. So is it possible to content project this ion-label every time. I need to be implemented with content projection as instead of ion-label could be anything, so will be passed in declarative way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a the label as a template and then reuse the template inside your component. In the component add a new input called *labelTemplate* that is passed a **TemplateRef**.  Then in the view, you can reference it like any template - I assumed you wanted it nested in the template you provided in your example, but there is no reason it couldn't be in the main for loop block.

```
export class MyComponentComponent {
  /** The template used to display the label */
  @Input() labelTemplate?: TemplateRef<{ $implicit: unknown }>;
}
```

```
<ng-template #tmpContent let-item="item">
  <div>
    {{item.id}}
    <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="labelTemplate; context: {$implicit: item.name }" />
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

In the consuming component's html template, add a label template anywhere within the markup - it doesn't have to be projected.  The reference to the template is passed to the *labelTemplate* property attribute on the *my-component* element.

```
<my-component dataProvider='source' [labelTemplate]="label">
  <ng-template #label let-content>
    <ion-label> test </ion-label>
  </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

Comment: Yes , its working and exactly what I am looked for.  Maybe not the best as this : "<ng-template #label let-content>" still needed to be declared when used the component , but I suppose there is no way to avoid this. Thank you , for the solution.